# In the Destiny universe, are the Hive Worm Gods synonymous with the Ahamkara?

Tags: dragons, destiny

In most Grimoire regarding the Ahamkara, they are described as a large, dragon-like species with wish-granting powers regarded as "magic" by those who encounter them. Despite their ability to grant immense amounts of knowledge, the demanded cost for such knowledge was eventually deemed too great by the Vanguard, who hunted them to (supposedly) extinction.

The Worm Gods on Fundament seem to be similar to the Ahamkara in many ways, most namely their speech patterns and ability to "grant" wishes. They even describe themselves as having jaws and wings, despite the physical form of Xol (encountered on Mars) seemed to lack wings entirely.

Are they both Ahamakara? Where the Hive Gods are directly in service of the Darkness, the question of whether or not the Ahamkara do is uncertain.

Comment: Oh my apologies, I totally misread your final sentence and thought it was "were" and not "where". Sorry.

Comment: That's okay, it was a confusing sentence!